# Dynamic Programming Approach

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming

when we are trying to solve a problem with dynamic programming. we have to follow some general steps

1. characterize the solution structure
2. Recursively define optimal solution
3. compute the value from bottom up fashion

Can anyone briefly explain the steps for this problem scenario. we need a 444 meter rope. but we have only small pieces of ropes. then we have to find out the minimum number of pieces of rope needs to construct that large rope.

**Length**---->**Quantity**

- 50m--->10
- 45m--->12
- 30m--->3
- 8m---->12
- 3m---->2
- 2m---->2

Comment: In the guideline, you should also make sure that you store the sub-solutions appropriately. I think the more important thing is making sure you characterize the problem so that you don't end up doing brute force search.

Comment: Do you need *exactly* or *at least* 444 meters?

Comment: you just glue them, end-to-end, or do you lose some length for putting them together? - can you cut them?

Comment: need exactly 444 metres and we can't cut the ropes

Comment: This is the subset sum problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia page to the Knapsack Problem has a nice explanation of a dynamic programming algorithm for it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

The knapsack problem is *very* similar to your problem - just define length of rope to be equal to their "weight" and use a uniform cost for all of them.